# Convert utf8 string to emoji, Swift

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, emoji

Given the following:

```
                       ["name":"CAT FACE WITH WRY SMILE", "utf":"1F63C"],
                       ["name":"KISSING CAT FACE WITH CLOSED EYES", "utf":"1F63D"],
                       ["name":"POUTING CAT FACE", "utf":"1F63E"],
                       ["name":"CRYING CAT FACE", "utf":"1F63F"]
```

How do I convert the utf part into an emoji, e.g. , in a scalable, performant way (there are thousands of these)

I tried something like:

```
String(utf8String: utf.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the string into a hexadecimal integer, and then into a `UnicodeScalar`.

Here's how you can convert a basic string:

```
let str = "1F63C"
let result = UnicodeScalar(Int(str, radix: 16)!)!
print(result)
```

> Prints:

And your more complicated example:

```
let arr = [
    ["name":"CAT FACE WITH WRY SMILE", "utf":"1F63C"],
    ["name":"KISSING CAT FACE WITH CLOSED EYES", "utf":"1F63D"],
    ["name":"POUTING CAT FACE", "utf":"1F63E"],
    ["name":"CRYING CAT FACE", "utf":"1F63F"]
]

for element in arr {
    let result = UnicodeScalar(Int(element["utf"]!, radix: 16)!)!
    print("\(element["name"]!): \(result)")
}
```

> Prints:
>
> ```
> CAT FACE WITH WRY SMILE: 
> KISSING CAT FACE WITH CLOSED EYES: 
> POUTING CAT FACE: 
> CRYING CAT FACE:
> ```

Note: there are a lot of force-unwraps. Ideally you would handle these in your own sensible way.

Comment: Why not `UInt32`? Thats what it is.

Comment: @LeoDabus I may be being stupid, what difference does that make (faster)?